# Paypal Hosted Solution Pro (Iframe) - Many wrong order created

Tags: orders, paypal, iframe

I'm using paypal Hosted Solution PRO as payment method on my store.

The integration is using API and Iframe.

The issue is that even if the customer doesn't finalize the purchase, an order is generate ( just when the iframe appears )

Any why to change this behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, this sound like a normal behavior. Order should be generated after clicking Place Order. That is before redirecting order to paypal. If customer does not finalize purchase, the order should be automatically cancelled. So your 'wrong orders' should be cancelled orders and this behavior is what it should be :)

Comment: Ok thanks for make it more clear, I will crosscheck and let you know.